# Tutorials Implementing a realtime Cartesian controller

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying this tutorial

> http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Implementing a realtime Cartesian
> controller

the previews tutorials was good.

When i'm trying to run the rosmake then to do the changes in this tutorial, i get the Next error:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['my_controller_pkg']               
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['my_controller_pkg']                       
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-112300
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['my_controller_pkg'] to:
['my_controller_pkg']       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pr2_hardware_interface [ make ]                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pr2_hardware_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_hardware_interface
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl_parser [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl_parser           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> my_controller_pkg [ make ]                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_mechanism_model [ make ]                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_mechanism_model ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_mechanism_model
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pr2_controller_interface [ make ]                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pr2_controller_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package pr2_controller_interface
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesy_controller_pkg: 0.4 sec ]  [ 1 Active 20/21 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package my_controller_pkg
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests my_controller_pkg
  [rospack] Error: package/stack my_controller_pkg depends on non-existent package eigen
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'my_controller_pkg'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.
    Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:13 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package my_controller_pkg written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-112300/my_controller_pkg/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< my_controller_pkg [FAIL] [ 0.44 seconds ]              
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package my_controller_pkg. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 21 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-112300
```

I tought that was the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH doesn't find the pkg that i'm using, but y export it and nothing is better.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47649/tutorials-implementing-a-realtime-cartesian-controller/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2012-11-07**:
i'm using fuerte, and check the explanation on the page you given Ricky and doesn't work, i tried to run rosmake eigen and it's fails
[

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-07**:
Does rosmake eigen fail due to  Error: package/stack my_controller_pkg depends on non-existent package xxx again?

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2012-11-07**:
Packages requested are: ['eigen']/Logging to directory /home/moni/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-120355 /Expanded args ['eigen'] to: / WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['eigen'] /ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error happened because you don't have "eigen" package installed.

Normally, you can solve this kind of question by getting the source on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen/diamondback),then rosmake eigen should solve this problem.

But note that eigen has been deprecated since ros-electric, so don't do that. Check the explanation on [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen#Fuerte).

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ready!

1. just use the kdl, copy the codes with kdl the file.h and file.cpp
2. in the manifest.xml erease the depend of eigen and run now rosmake

---

Originally posted by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) with karma: 92 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-07**:
that's good.